PSPP multiple variable linear regression analysis
I'm just starting with linear regression, and I'm having trouble understanding it. It doesn't seem to make any sense to me. Yes, this is school work, but instead of asking for direct answers, I need guidance. I need to understand linear regression because I'll need it later for machine learning. At least I think so.
The dependent variable is weight, and the independent variables are height, age, dark bread consumption, and white bread consumption. How can I check in PSPP if I can include all these variables in a regression model? Or should I drop some of those out.

I would include them all in the regression and see which ones have substantial vs. non-substantial regression weights (slope coefficients). You can also look at the statistical significance (p values) associated with the slope coefficients to find out which predictors are statistically significantly related to the DV.

Setting the software aspect of this question completely to the side, there is nothing stopping you from adding any number of predictors in a model. PSPP isn't different in that respect. But how you should do that will depend largely on what you are trying to achieve.
If your goal is simply to see which predictors have the largest association with the outcome, then what Christian already said stands here. If you are trying to tease apart which predictors should be included and which shouldn't be, that is more a theory question. Your variables seem to be related in some way to caloric intake (dark/white bread consumption) and biological factors (age, weight, height), so I'm guessing there is some hypothesis you have about that, and should be tested in that way. If for example bread color doesn't really matter for your hypothesis, then it should be excluded if your sole purpose is investigating caloric intake, where a generic calorie measure would perhaps be better.
In the future, you may run into situations where you have far more predictors to choose from, where variable selection is a lot more critical, particularly with a much more limited number of observations. Here variable selection can include selecting a subset of variables based on previous literature ("which variables make sense"), regularization techniques ("how can I penalize some predictors and leave others in"), dimension reduction ("can I put a bunch of these together in a meaningfulway?"), along with other considerations. All of that will depend on each case you run into, but I think your situation isn't as complicated based off the limited information provided.
